# how to check if user is logged in before a view without devise RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

How do I check if a user is logged in, for example I want the /sheets/view to be only accessible to logged in users, I am using bcrypt, how can I do this? any help/ideas

(NOT USING DEVISE)

Comment: How do you log a `user` in? How does your login method look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it, I did: (in application controller)

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user

  def authorize
    redirect_to '/login' unless current_user
  end
```

and put  `before_action :authorize` on the view controller